# Distributed Testing using Jmeter; Retrieving logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, distributed

I'm doing distributed testing using JMeter and I have a remote server in AWS. Using Jmeter 2.12, I have my setup similar to the instructions: [Setting up JMeter for Distributed testing in AWS with connectivity issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618915/setting-up-jmeter-for-distributed-testing-in-aws-with-connectivity-issues)

However, I've been unable to record the JTL files for the tests being run.

When I use

```
sh jmeter.sh -n -t /jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.12/tests/ABC.jmx -l results.jtl -r
```

the test will execute but the results.jtl file is not being created when connecting with my remote server

If I remove the -r flag (thus not doing distributed testing), the log file will generate;

How do I generate the .JTL file after testing using the remote server?

Comment: Maybe it's related to permission. check it is on writable folder. Set writable permission on that folder or try to do it with sudo or just point jtl file in home directory just like this.
sh jmeter.sh -n -t /jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.12/tests/ABC.jmx -l /home/ubuntu/results.jtl

Comment: It's not a permission issue. I've done all of these. it seems strictly related to the -r flag. I suspect there's something to change in jmeter.properties, but I haven't found anything online.

Comment: So you could try this: 
sh jmeter.sh -n -t /jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.12/tests/ABC.jmx -l /home/ubuntu/results.jtl -R server1,server2...