# Jmeter - Connection refused to host: abc

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter

I am trying to connect apache jmeter with amazon EC2, I have configured Jmeter in the amazon instance. I followed [Setting up JMeter for Distributed testing in AWS with connectivity issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618915/setting-up-jmeter-for-distributed-testing-in-aws-with-connectivity-issues) in order to configure Jmeter.
At the client, I edited jmeter.properties and set remote_hosts parameter with public DNS, then when I try to remotely connect with amazon instance it gives me following error:

```
Connection refused to host: abc.compute.amazonaws.com; nested exception is: java.net ConnectException: Connection timeout:connect
```

Where am I going wrong? Kindly assist me

Comment: The directions and information in the post about Setting up JMeter with AWS are pretty detailed and discuss some issues where they had to setup reverse tunnels.   1 - did you confirm that you can connect via the public IP to those remote JMeter instances?  2 - What point are you up to in their steps?

Comment: Yes I can connect via public IP.
On the client side in jmeter.properties file i edited this remote_hosts=Public_IP. So am I going in the right direction?