# How to setup Master-Slave configuration in Azure server By using JMETER

Tags: jmeter, windows-server-2012-r2, master-slave

I am going to do performance testing by using **JMETER** in **Azure server**. I want to setup **Master-Slave** configuration to create Virtual Users.

Kindly help me in this to set up this process.

Comment: See this Thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618915/setting-up-jmeter-for-distributed-testing-in-aws-with-connectivity-issues