# Connection refused error while connecting to jmeter slave docker container

Tags: java, docker, performance, jmeter, rmi

I'm trying to implement Jmeter distributed framework with Docker. Master and slaves are running on different hosts in ec2. Ports have been opened to allow communication.

Master is stuck with the below message

```
Starting distributed test with remote engines: [slaveIP:1099] @ Sun Nov 21 04:50:29 GMT 2021 (1637470229447)
Remote engines have been started:[slaveIP:1099]
```

On the slave side, it is throwing me connection refused errors.

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.17.0.2; nested exception is:
```

Command to start slave machine:

```
docker run \
        -dit \
        -p 6000:6000 \
        -p 1099:1099 \
        -v "${volume_path}":${jmeter_path} \
        --rm \
        jmeter \
        -n -s \
        -Jclient.rmi.localport=3000 \
        -Jserver.rmi.localport=6000 \
        -Dserver_port=1099 \
        -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<HostIP> \
        -Dserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true \
        -j ${jmeter_path}/server/slave_${timestamp}_${IP_ADD}.log
```

Command to start master

```
docker run \
  -v "${volume_path}":${jmeter_path} \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  --rm \
  jmeternew \
  -n -X \
   -t ${jmeter_path}/$1 \
  -Dserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true \
  -Dclient.rmi.localport=3000 \
  -R slaveIP:1099 \
  -l ${jmeter_path}/client/result_${timestamp}.jtl \
  -j ${jmeter_path}/client/jmeter_${timestamp}.log
```

The same commands are working if I'm running master and slave on the same machine.
I tried changing the java.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0.
It's also throwing me connection refused error

Comment: #1 In which of parameter of master docker run, are you setting the slave ip? #2 Master and client has different ips? Are these ips public or exist in the same network?

Comment: What jmeter docker image are you using?

Comment: @JRichardsz -R parameter is used to set slave IP.#2. Yes, both are in the same subnet.I've also checked the network connectivity between master and slave on all used ports

Comment: @JRichardsz I've followed the Blazemeter blog https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker to create the image

Answer (score 0):

According to :

- https://www.guru99.com/jmeter-distributed-testing.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/jmeter-distributed-testing
- [JMeter with remote servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712080/jmeter-with-remote-servers/31021802)
- https://medium.com/@Muhammad.Ali.Nisar/jmeter-master-slave-configuration-fe38fc890ca
- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

Just we need:

- configure the slave machine
- configure the run machine
- add the slave ip/ips on the master using the file **jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties**

```
  remote_hosts=192.165.0.10,192.165.0.20,192.165.0.30
```

- the main and slave ports are randomly assigned so you should use parameters: **client.rmi.localport and server.rmi.localport** respectively.
- then start the master jmeter
- then start the slave jmeter and the connection will be established.

### advice

Establish the connection with docker, following and of the several tutorials on the internet. This will help you to detect errors like:

- firewalls permissions
- ports configuration on master and slave
- public/private network restrictions
- etc

If it works, then use docker to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using `172.17.0.2` which is kind of local network address for [Class B networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network#Classful_addressing_definition) so your "hosts" might not be able to reach each other, try using [public IP addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html) instead
2. You will need to open the RMI ports in your OS [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) and in [EC2 security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)
3. I fail to see why would you need docker there, it doesn't add any value and only making things more complicated and consumes resources
4. I fail to see the reason for going for the distributed testing there, one master and one slave is equal to one "load generator" machine which means that you can just [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) from a single host and get the same results.